# Unable to reach the Application UI deployed on a Kubernetes system

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-ingress, microk8s, k3s

I have deployed a gerrit container and exposed the ports but unable to reach the UI.
This is deployed on microk8s on AWS. I'm not using ingress

The Image is an official image from the docker hub.

https://hub.docker.com/r/k8sgerrit/gerrit-master

My code

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: gerrit-deployment
  labels:
    app: gerrit-meta
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: gerrit
      type: frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: gerrit
        type: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: gerrit
        image: k8sgerrit/gerrit
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        - containerPort: 29418
```

Services File

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: gerrit-service

spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 30010
  selector:
      app: gerrit
      type: frontend
```

```sh
root@ip-172-31-3-35:~/microk8s/gerrit312# kubectl get deployments
NAME                READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
gerrit-deployment   1/1     1            1           21m
root@ip-172-31-3-35:~/microk8s/gerrit312# kubectl get services
NAME             TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
gerrit-service   NodePort    10.152.183.210   <none>        80:30010/TCP   6m6s
kubernetes       ClusterIP   10.152.183.1     <none>        443/TCP        34
```

```yaml
root@ip-172-31-3-35:~/microk8s/gerrit312# kubectl describe deployment gerrit-deployment
Name:                   gerrit-deployment
Namespace:              default
CreationTimestamp:      Thu, 23 Jul 2020 20:37:47 +0000
Labels:                 app=gerrit-meta
Annotations:            deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 1
Selector:               app=gerrit,type=frontend
Replicas:               1 desired | 1 updated | 1 total | 1 available | 0 unavailable
StrategyType:           RollingUpdate
MinReadySeconds:        0
RollingUpdateStrategy:  25% max unavailable, 25% max surge
Pod Template:
  Labels:  app=gerrit
           type=frontend
  Containers:
   gerrit:
    Image:        k8sgerrit/gerrit
    Ports:        80/TCP, 29418/TCP
    Host Ports:   0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:       <none>
  Volumes:        <none>
Conditions:
  Type           Status  Reason
  ----           ------  ------
  Progressing    True    NewReplicaSetAvailable
  Available      True    MinimumReplicasAvailable
OldReplicaSets:  <none>
NewReplicaSet:   gerrit-deployment-854ccc4d97 (1/1 replicas created)
Events:
  Type    Reason             Age   From                   Message
  ----    ------             ----  ----                   -------
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  21m   deployment-controller  Scaled up replica set gerrit-deployment-854ccc4d97 to 1
root@ip-172-31-3-35:~/microk8s/gerrit312#
root@ip-172-31-3-35:~/microk8s/gerrit312# kubectl describe services gerrit-service
Name:                     gerrit-service
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=gerrit,type=frontend
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.152.183.210
Port:                     <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30010/TCP
Endpoints:                10.1.88.88:80
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Any help to understand why the UI is not accessible is greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Anish

Comment: How exactly are you trying to access the UI?

Comment: The service should be running on nodeip:30010? If your vm has browser access then go to http://localhost:30010

Comment: I redeployed the service now it has a new IP

Comment: root@ip-172-31-3-35:~/microk8s/gerrit312# curl http://10.152.183.116:30010
^C
root@ip-172-31-3-35:~/microk8s/gerrit312# curl --insecure https://10.152.183.116:30010
^C
root@ip-172-31-3-35:~/microk8s/gerrit312# curl --insecure http://10.152.183.116:80
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.152.183.116 port 80: Connection refused

Comment: It simply doesnt connect

Comment: kubectl get ep gerrit-service
NAME             ENDPOINTS   AGE
gerrit-service   <none>      8m6s

I'm using the public IP of the AWS VM to connect to the UI

Answer (score 1):

Managed to fix it. It was a problem with the port and the nodes were cordoned since it was running short of space